# Agent version 2.173.0 fails to connect to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

**Agent Version and Platform**

2.173.0
on
centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64

It's a release agent for a deployment pool.

**Azure DevOps Type and Version**

dev.azure.com (cloud)

**What's not working?**

```
# Running run once with agent version 2.160.1
./run.sh --once
Scanning for tool capabilities.
Connecting to the server.
2020-08-25 21:31:02Z: Listening for Jobs
Agent update in progress, do not shutdown agent.
Downloading 2.173.0 agent
Waiting for current job finish running.
Generate and execute update script.
Agent will exit shortly for update, should back online within 10 seconds.
‘/root/azagent/_diag/SelfUpdate-20200825-213148.log’ -> ‘/root/azagent/_diag/SelfUpdate-20200825-213148.log.succeed’
Scanning for tool capabilities.
Connecting to the server. 
# this now runs indefinitely
```

Is there a way to stop the auto update? Multiple agents on production machines are offline and I have, as of now, no idea how to fix that.

[agent.log](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/files/5126469/agent.log)

Edit: It is a Release Agent in a Deployment Group. Also, there is a Github issue now https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/3093

Comment: did you see this line `[2020-08-25 21:31:58Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Authentication failed with status code 401.` in your logs? Looks like the agent get a 401. Does the user running the agent have the correct permissions?

Comment: You can stop the auto update, Agent Pools=>Settings=>Disable the `Allow agents in this pool to automatically update`.

Comment: @Gimly The user is the root user and should have all necessary permissions, yes.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT The agent is a release agent, so this setting is unavailable. There is also an issue on GitHub now (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/3093).

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the `Authentication failed with status code 401` you can try steps below:

1.Create a new PAT with `manage` permission:

[image]

Then reconfigure the agent with `config.sh` file.

2.If that not works, try creating a new Agent pool to register new agents:

[image]

To stop the auto update, you should disable this option (**Organization settings**=>Agent Pools=>Settings):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this agent is a release agent so this setting is unavailable.